# Python: urllib/urllib2/httplib confusion

Tags: python, http, urllib2

I'm trying to test the functionality of a web app by scripting a login sequence in Python, but I'm having some troubles.

Here's what I need to do:

1. Do a POST with a few parameters and headers.
2. Follow a redirect
3. Retrieve the HTML body.

Now, I'm relatively new to python, but the two things I've tested so far haven't worked. First I used httplib, with putrequest() (passing the parameters within the URL), and putheader(). This didn't seem to follow the redirects.

Then I tried urllib and urllib2, passing both headers and parameters as dicts. This seems to return the login page, instead of the page I'm trying to login to, I guess it's because of lack of cookies or something.

Am I missing something simple?

Thanks.

Comment: Use the python requests library.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Focus on `urllib2` for this, it works quite well.  Don't mess with `httplib`, it's not the top-level API.

What you're noting is that `urllib2` doesn't follow the redirect.

You need to fold in an instance of `HTTPRedirectHandler` that will catch and follow the redirects.

Further, you may want to subclass the default `HTTPRedirectHandler` to capture information that you'll then check as part of your unit testing.

```
cookie_handler= urllib2.HTTPCookieProcessor( self.cookies )
redirect_handler= HTTPRedirectHandler()
opener = urllib2.build_opener(redirect_handler,cookie_handler)
```

You can then use this `opener` object to POST and GET, handling redirects and cookies properly.

You may want to add your own subclass of `HTTPHandler` to capture and log various error codes, also.

Comment: urllib2.urlopen seems to handle redirects just fine.

Comment: @Sridhar I've found that too - urllib2.urlopen follows redirects perfectly.

Answer (score 15):

Here's my take on this issue.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import urllib
import urllib2


class HttpBot:
    """an HttpBot represents one browser session, with cookies."""
    def __init__(self):
        cookie_handler= urllib2.HTTPCookieProcessor()
        redirect_handler= urllib2.HTTPRedirectHandler()
        self._opener = urllib2.build_opener(redirect_handler, cookie_handler)

    def GET(self, url):
        return self._opener.open(url).read()

    def POST(self, url, parameters):
        return self._opener.open(url, urllib.urlencode(parameters)).read()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    bot = HttpBot()
    ignored_html = bot.POST('https://example.com/authenticator', {'passwd':'foo'})
    print bot.GET('https://example.com/interesting/content')
    ignored_html = bot.POST('https://example.com/deauthenticator',{})
```

Comment: This is the only answer that actually makes this process simple.

Answer (score 13):

@S.Lott, thank you. Your suggestion worked for me, with some modification. Here's how I did it.

```
data = urllib.urlencode(params)
url = host+page
request = urllib2.Request(url, data, headers)
response = urllib2.urlopen(request)

cookies = CookieJar()
cookies.extract_cookies(response,request)

cookie_handler= urllib2.HTTPCookieProcessor( cookies )
redirect_handler= HTTPRedirectHandler()
opener = urllib2.build_opener(redirect_handler,cookie_handler)

response = opener.open(request)
```

Answer (score 11):

I had to do this exact thing myself recently.  I only needed classes from the standard library.  Here's an excerpt from my code:

```
from urllib import urlencode
from urllib2 import urlopen, Request

# encode my POST parameters for the login page
login_qs = urlencode( [("username",USERNAME), ("password",PASSWORD)] )

# extract my session id by loading a page from the site
set_cookie = urlopen(URL_BASE).headers.getheader("Set-Cookie")
sess_id = set_cookie[set_cookie.index("=")+1:set_cookie.index(";")]

# construct headers dictionary using the session id
headers = {"Cookie": "session_id="+sess_id}

# perform login and make sure it worked
if "Announcements:" not in urlopen(Request(URL_BASE+"login",headers=headers), login_qs).read():
    print "Didn't log in properly"
    exit(1)

# here's the function I used after this for loading pages
def download(page=""):
    return urlopen(Request(URL_BASE+page, headers=headers)).read()

# for example:
print download(URL_BASE + "config")
```

Answer (score 8):

I'd give Mechanize (http://wwwsearch.sourceforge.net/mechanize/) a shot. It may well handle your cookie/headers transparently.

Answer (score 6):

Try [twill](http://twill.idyll.org/) - a simple language that allows users to browse the Web from a command-line interface. With twill, you can navigate through Web sites that use forms, cookies, and most standard Web features. More to the point, *twill* is written in `Python` and has a [python API](http://twill.idyll.org/python-api.html), e.g:

```
from twill import get_browser
b = get_browser()

b.go("http://www.python.org/")
b.showforms()
```

Answer (score 0):

Besides the fact that you may be missing a cookie, there might be some field(s) in the form that you are not POSTing to the webserver. The best way would be to capture the actual POST from a web browser. You can use [LiveHTTPHeaders](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/3829)  or [WireShark](http://www.wireshark.org/) to snoop the traffic and mimic the same behaviour in your script.

Comment: Thanks for a good Firefox addon tip :) But no, I seem to be passing the necessary headers and data.

Answer (score 0):

[Funkload](http://funkload.nuxeo.org/) is a great web app testing tool also.  It wraps webunit to handle the browser emulation, then gives you both functional and load testing features on top.