# How do I use Python's httplib to send a POST to a URL, with a dictionary of parameters?

Tags: python, api, post, httplib

I just want a function that can take 2 parameters:

- the URL to POST to
- a dictionary of parameters

How can this be done with httplib? thanks.

Comment: Please use urllib2.   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/321582/urllib2-data-sending.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

From the [Python documentation](https://docs.python.org/release/2.7/library/httplib.html#examples):

```
>>> import httplib, urllib
>>> params = urllib.urlencode({'spam': 1, 'eggs': 2, 'bacon': 0})
>>> headers = {"Content-type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
...            "Accept": "text/plain"}
>>> conn = httplib.HTTPConnection("musi-cal.mojam.com:80")
>>> conn.request("POST", "/cgi-bin/query", params, headers)
>>> response = conn.getresponse()
>>> print response.status, response.reason
200 OK
>>> data = response.read()
>>> conn.close()
```

Comment: Credit where credit is due: this was ripped off directly from http://docs.python.org/release/2.6/library/httplib.html (or 2.5.2 or earlier, it hasn't changed much over the years)

Comment: Do the params need to be in that format? can they be raw text?

Comment: Yes you can pass in raw text as params, `urllib.urlencode` just takes care of url encoding the string to be passed, if you print it out you will see that its just a string

Answer (score 11):

A simpler one, using just urllib:

```
import urllib
params = urllib.urlencode({'spam': 1, 'eggs': 2, 'bacon': 0})
f = urllib.urlopen("http://www.example.org/cgi-bin/query", params)
print f.read()
```

Found in Python docs for [urllib module](http://docs.python.org/2/library/urllib.html#examples)

Comment: sorry, but this most probably does a HTTP GET, not a POST

Comment: @hko No, it's from the POST example on that urllib page.  Note that params are added with `, params` instead of `% params`.