# Using Project Oxford's Emotion API

Tags: python, python-2.7, azure-cognitive-services

I came across Project Oxford and became really interested in it and using its API, specifically the emotion one. Microsoft provides sample code

```
########### Python 2.7 #############
import httplib, urllib, base64

headers = {
    # Request headers
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    'Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key': 'add key',

}

params = urllib.urlencode({
    # Request parameters
    'faceRectangles': '{string}',

})

try:
    conn = httplib.HTTPSConnection('api.projectoxford.ai')
    conn.request("POST", "/emotion/v1.0/recognize&%s" % params, "{body}", headers)
    response = conn.getresponse()
    data = response.read()
    print(data)
    conn.close()

except Exception as e:
    print("[Errno {0}] {1}".format(e.errno, e.strerror))
```

This doesn't contain the request body. I thought all I need to add was

```
body = {
    'url': 'url here',
}
```

and change

```
   conn.request("POST", "/emotion/v1.0/recognize&%s" % params, "{body}",headers)
```

to

```
conn.request("POST", "/emotion/v1.0/recognize&%s" % params, body, headers)
```

However that isn't working. I am getting this when I run it

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:/Users/User/Desktop/python/emotion.py", line 29, in <module>
print("[Errno {0}] {1}".format(e.errno, e.strerror))
AttributeError: 'exceptions.TypeError' object has no attribute 'errno'
```

Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: change `print("[Errno {0}] {1}".format(e.errno, e.strerror))` to `print(e.message)` to get the proper error message.

Comment: @sobolevn The error message is "unhashable type"

Comment: @sobolevn The exception is being thrown after conn.request("POST", "/emotion/v1.0/recognize&%s" % params, body, headers)

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2370003/how-do-i-use-pythons-httplib-to-send-a-post-to-a-url-with-a-dictionary-of-para

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following works for me (Python 2.7), also based on the sample code provided by MSDN. You don't need to specify faceRectangles (unless you want to because they've already been detected, to save compute time).

```
import httplib, urllib, base64  

# Image to analyse (body of the request)

body = '{\'URL\': \'https://<path to image>.jpg\'}'

# API request for Emotion Detection

headers = {
   'Content-type': 'application/json',
}

params = urllib.urlencode({
   'subscription-key': '',  # Enter EMOTION API key
   #'faceRectangles': '',
})

try:
   conn = httplib.HTTPSConnection('api.projectoxford.ai')
   conn.request("POST", "/emotion/v1.0/recognize?%s" % params, body , headers)
   response = conn.getresponse()
   print("Send request")

   data = response.read()
   print(data)
   conn.close()
except Exception as e:
   print("[Errno {0}] {1}".format(e.errno, e.strerror))
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to pass `str(body)` to the request.

Also, make sure to not include `params` if you don't have any face rectangles.