# In Python, how might one log in, answer a web form via HTTP POST (not url-encoded), and fetch a returned XML file?

Tags: python, authentication, cookies, post

I am basically trying to export a configuration file, once a week.  While the product in question allows you to log in manually via a web client, enter some information, and get an XML file back when you submit, there's no facility for automating this.  I can get away with using Python 2.5 (have used for a while) or 2.6 (unfamiliar) to do this.

1. I think I need to have some way to authenticate against the product.  Although I can view the cookie in Firefox, when I looked through the actual `cookie.txt` file, it was not present.  Didn't show up after clearing my private data and re-authenticating.  Odd.  Should I be shooting for the `Cookie` module, or could this be some arcane method of authentication that only *looks* like cookies?  How would I know?
2. I think I need the `httplib` module to do the HTTP POST, but I don't know how to do the `multipart/form-data` encoding.  Have I overlooked a handy option, or is this something where I must roll my own?
3. I assume I can get the XML file back in the `HTTPesponse` from `httplib`.

I've fetched web things via Python before, but not with POST, multipart encoding, and authentication in the mix.

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/393738/programmatic-form-submit.  Also Python 2.6 is so much like 2.5 you can't easily tell the difference.

Comment: Use the following URL to get relevant questions and answers: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=urllib2

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpython%5D+mechanize

Answer (score 3):

[urllib2](http://docs.python.org/library/urllib2.html) should cover all of this.

Here's a [Basic Authentication example](http://www.voidspace.org.uk/python/articles/urllib2.shtml#id6).

Here's a [Post with multipart/form-data](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/146306/).

Answer (score 2):

Try [mechanize](http://wwwsearch.sourceforge.net/mechanize/) module.

Answer (score 0):

You should look at the MultipartPostHandler:

http://odin.himinbi.org/MultipartPostHandler.py

And if you need to support unicode file names , see a fix at:
http://peerit.blogspot.com/2007/07/multipartposthandler-doesnt-work-for.html