# How to make download manager more robust?

Tags: python

I have made this simple download manager, but the problem is it wont work on complex urls, when pages are redirected.

```
def str(d):
    for i in range(len(d)):
        if d[-i] == '/':
            x=-i
            break
    s=[]
    l=len(d)+x+1
    print d[l],d[len(d)-1]

    s=d[l:]


    return s

import urllib2
url=raw_input()
filename=str(url)
webfile = urllib2.urlopen(url)
data = webfile.read()
fout =open(filename,"w")
fout.write(data)
fout.close()
webfile.close()
```

it wouldn't work for http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=9&ved=0CG0QFjAI&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.iasted.org%2Fconferences%2Fformatting%2FPresentations-Tips.ppt&ei=clfWTpjZEIblrAfC8qWXDg&usg=AFQjCNEIgqx6x4ULHFXzzYDzCITuUJOczA&sig2=0VtKXPvoDnIq-lIR4S9LEQ

while it would work for http://www.iasted.org/conferences/formatting/Presentations-Tips.ppt

and both links are for the same file.

**How to solve the problem of redirection?**

Comment: Why are you redefining `str`?

Comment: Looks like you are looking for this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/301924/python-urllib-urllib2-httplib-confusion

Comment: @MattFenwick i am just extracting the name out of the url stringso to name the file which i am writing on.

Comment: @kekoa thanks but it didnt really help

Comment: The problem is that i have to extract the name from the url ?   and    solve the problem of redirection?

Comment: You might want to look into the `requests` module which handles redirection automatically.

Answer (score 1):

I think redirection is not a problem here:
Since urllib2 already follows redirect automatically, google redirects to a page in case of error.

Try this script :

```
url1 = 'http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=9&ved=0CG0QFjAI&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.iasted.org%2Fconferences%2Fformatting%2FPresentations-Tips.ppt&ei=clfWTpjZEIblrAfC8qWXDg&usg=AFQjCNEIgqx6x4ULHFXzzYDzCITuUJOczA&sig2=0VtKXPvoDnIq-lIR4S9LEQ'

url2 = 'http://www.iasted.org/conferences/formatting/Presentations-Tips.ppt'

from urlparse import urlsplit
from urllib2 import urlopen

for url in [url1, url2]:
    split = urlsplit(url)
    filename =  split.path[split.path.rfind('/')+1:]
    if not filename:
        filename = split.query[split.query.rfind('/')+1:]
    f = open(filename, 'w')
    f.write(urlopen(url).read())
    f.close()

    # Yields 2 files : url and Presentations-Tips.ppt [Both are ppt files]
```

The above script works every time.

Comment: the urlparse rally seems to solve the problem totally thanks.

Comment: Accept the answer by clicking the tick - if that helped.

Answer (score 0):

In general, you handle redirection by using `urllib2.HTTPRedirectHandler`, like this:

```
import urllib2

opener = urllib.build_opener(urllib2.HTTPRedirectHandler)
res = open.open('http://example.com/some/url/')
```

However, it doesn't like like this will work for the Google URL you've given in your example, because rather than including a `Location` header in the response, the Google result looks like this:

```
<script>window.googleJavaScriptRedirect=1</script><script>var a=parent,b=parent.google,c=location;if(a!=window&&b){if(b.r){b.r=0;a.location.href="http://www.iasted.org/conferences/formatting/Presentations-Tips.ppt";c.replace("about:blank");}}else{c.replace("http://www.iasted.org/conferences/formatting/Presentations-Tips.ppt");};</script><noscript><META http-equiv="refresh" content="0;URL='http://www.iasted.org/conferences/formatting/Presentations-Tips.ppt'"></noscript>
```

...which is to say, it uses a Javascript redirect, which substantially complicates your life.  You could use Python's `re` module to extract the correct location from this block.